# Why is std::unordered_set slower than std::set?

Tags: c++, performance, set, unordered-set

I write a sample code to compare the performance of std::unordered_set with std::set.

```
  constexpr size_t kLoopNumber = 10000000;

  std::default_random_engine e;
  std::set<uint32_t> s1;
  std::unordered_set<uint32_t> s2;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    uint32_t k = e();
    s1.emplace(k);
    s2.emplace(k);
  }

  std::vector<size_t> indices(kLoopNumber);
  std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

  // std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), e);

  size_t count = 0;
  auto pre = system_clock::now();
  // code 0
  for (size_t i = 0; i < kLoopNumber; ++i) {
    count += s1.count(indices[i]);
  }
  //
  std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now() - pre).count()
            << " us for set" << std::endl;

  pre = system_clock::now();
  // code 1
  for (size_t i = 0; i < kLoopNumber; ++i) {
    count += s2.count(indices[i]);
  }
  //
  std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now() - pre).count()
            << " us for unordered_set" << std::endl;
  // for not optimize count
  std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Get the following result:

```
85434 us for set
144212 us for unordered_set
```

If I shuffle the indices.

```
  constexpr size_t kLoopNumber = 10000000;

  std::default_random_engine e;
  std::set<uint32_t> s1;
  std::unordered_set<uint32_t> s2;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    uint32_t k = e();
    s1.emplace(k);
    s2.emplace(k);
  }

  std::vector<size_t> indices(kLoopNumber);
  std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

  std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), e);

  size_t count = 0;
  auto pre = system_clock::now();
  // code 0
  for (size_t i = 0; i < kLoopNumber; ++i) {
    count += s1.count(indices[i]);
  }
  //
  std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now() - pre).count()
            << " us for set" << std::endl;

  pre = system_clock::now();
  // code 1
  for (size_t i = 0; i < kLoopNumber; ++i) {
    count += s2.count(indices[i]);
  }
  //
  std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now() - pre).count()
            << " us for unordered_set" << std::endl;
  // for not optimize count
  std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Then get:

```
225042 us for set
160389 us for unordered_set
```

Why the profile change so much after a shuffle, can someone explain an essential reason? Cpu cache? Ordered set key? Or another reason?

Tips:
The compiler is gcc 7.5.0 with the compile option `g++ -std=c++17 -O2`.

PS: I update the sample code referring to comment suggestions.

Comment: Some issues; you need to make sure that your're compiling with full optimization, and you need to make sure that the result is stored somewhere (i.e accumulate the value of s.count(i) and print it) so that the compiler does not determinate it can throw away the result.
Also, put the system_clock::now() outside of the std::cout.

Comment: You might use https://quick-bench.com/ for online benchmark.

Comment: Also you should try reversing the order of the tests, or populate-and-test the set and then populate-and-test the unordered set. At the moment you're likely to evict the unordered set from cache while timing the ordered version.

Comment: As with most things, the simplified algorithmic complexity analysis (constant for hash-table v logarithmic for b-tree) does not always translate in reality, there are implementation details and hardware consideration.

Comment: unorderded set has amortized constant `emplace` while set has logarithmic emplace. Same for `count`. However thats only complexity, ie all constant factors ignored and to get the full picture you'd need to vary the size of the sets. Runtime for one specifc `N` can be completely different

Comment: Your `indices` version doesn't make sense: you need to store `k`, not a new number from the same PRNG.

Comment: When I run the same logic on [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/0Zxx2jqn6EPx_9xOh2XfzAZ-AqQ), with some obvious problems fixed - the unordered version is 2-3 times faster. You need to get you benchmarks working & calibrated before you take their results seriously.

Comment: @Useless try running your benchmark with libc++ instead of libstdc++.

Comment: I'm less invested in the result, than in pointing out that the original is a bad test giving a low-quality result, and that you should always try to rule out confounding effects _before_ posting on SO.

Comment: Something having a lower asymptotic complexity does not mean that it is faster on every workload, only there is some input size above which it is faster.

Comment: @Useless Changing compiler to GCC 7.5 also gets a different result from your benchmark.

Comment: @Useless The sample code has been updated according to your valuable suggestions. Thx.

Comment: Ah yes, I see you edited in the compiler version. Well, the reason is still hard to determine exactly, because the unordered_set::count call is not inlined (conversely, the set::count seems to be inlined completely). Is that enough explanation? If not you need to profile down into that call and see where the time goes.